# Comment tag @code doesn't work with properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, documentation, comments

I'm documenting my Objective-C code for the Quick help function in Xcode like this:

[image]

but I have a little problem in documenting the **properties**: it's possibile use the tag **@code** ?

Because this comment doesn't work:

```
/** 
 the URL base for backend APIs
 @code
 codeexample;
 @endcode
*/
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *baseUrl;
```

but this works:

```
/** 
 the URL base for backend APIs
*/
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *baseUrl;
```

Maybe **@code** tag can not be used with properties? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you running? It works for me: http://imgur.com/NjMubEa

Comment: Xcode 6.3.1... I tried clean & build also but nothing :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That style of documentation doesn't work with properties, only methods. That's why @psobko's example works and your doesn't. They documented a method definition.